# Scons: how to force rebuild?

Tags: linux, makefile, scons, rebuild

When using make, I can specify `make -B` to force rebuild.

But how specify it with scons, to force rebuild `all` or force rebuild specific folders?

Comment: So you don't want to clean first?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
scons --clean [targets]
scons --no-cache [targets]
```

Reference: http://scons.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=438

Comment: Hmmm, `--clean` will likely clean the build, which `make -B` does not really do?